How do I configure the ServerCertificate in websocket-sharp using any command on windows box?
Currently we are configuring the certificate using the UICertificate Configuration UI
I am using below code:
server.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2 (
                                            "/path/to/cert.pfx", "password for cert.pfx"
                                          );

I was using the HttpServer class given by the websocket-sharp library and trying to configure the ServerCertificate using any command on windows box because I don't like to submit the pfx file and password as specified here -> https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp
When I executed the netsh command and attempted to connect to HttpServer, I received an exception.
Error:An exception has occurred while connecting. Code: 1006
When we use the HTTP protocol we were able to configure the certificate using netsh command as below:
netsh http add sslcert ipport=ip:port certhash={Cert-Hash} appid={GUID}
If we want to remove the configuration from UI we want to understand is there any alternate way to configure this using any other way(commands)?
To configure the ServerCertificate, I used the command netsh http add sslcert as below to configure the ssl certificate.
netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:8443 certhash={Cert-Hash} appid={GUID}
However, after connecting to HttpServer, I received the error ->
Error:An exception has occurred while connecting. Code: 1006
Server code:
using WebSocketSharp.Server;
private HttpServer server = new HttpServer("https://127.0.0.1:8443/");
server.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols |= SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.Tls12;

Client code:
using WebSocketSharp;
private WebSocket client = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:8443/");
client.Connect();

